# How to get feedback from ComboBoxes created in a loop

Tags: python, dynamic, qcombobox, pyqt6

I am trying to feed an unspecified number of comboboxes to a user. Once the user selects inputs for the combo boxes I want to be able to print out those combobox inputs after the submit button is clicked. Currently I can only print the last one because my comboboxes are being overwritten. I thought to do a cb.format(i) and call each respectively but I was unable to get it to work.

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(200, 200)

        self.centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.lay = QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.MakeButtons(5)

    def MakeButtons(self, x):
        for i in range(x):
            self.cb = QComboBox(self) 
            self.cb.addItem("ID")
            self.cb.addItem("Num")
            self.cb.addItem("Bi")
            self.cb.addItem("Cat")
            self.lay.addWidget(self.cb)
        self.btn = QPushButton('Submit', self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.printingaction)

    def printingaction(self):
        #print('Current item: {0}'.format( self.cb.currentIndex() )) # ComboBox's index
        print('Current index: {0}'.format( self.cb.currentText() )) # ComboBox's text

app = QApplication([])
window = Window()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collect the combo boxes into a list and then iterate the list when the submit button is pressed.

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(200, 200)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.lay = QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.boxes = []  # list of combo boxes
        self.MakeButtons(5)

    def MakeButtons(self, x):
        for _ in range(x):
            cb = QComboBox(self)
            cb.addItem("ID")
            cb.addItem("Num")
            cb.addItem("Bi")
            cb.addItem("Cat")
            self.boxes.append(cb)
            self.lay.addWidget(cb)
        self.btn = QPushButton('Submit', self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.printingaction)

    def printingaction(self):
        for box in self.boxes:  # iterate list of combo boxes.
            print('Current index: {0}'.format(box.currentText()))
```